# (Linux) Bash: permission denined

Tags: linux, bash

this may be a pretty dumb question, but please forgive me for I'm only a novice in Linux.

I have 2 files created by command vi (text0 and text1). I then used command `cat < text0 > text1` to copy the data in text0 to text 1, but I encountered an error 
"bash: permission denied".
So I changed the permission in both files text0 and text1 with `sudo chmod u+x program_name` but the problem remains.
Can someone please tell me what have I missed?

Comment: Add output of `ls -l text0 text1` to your question (no comment).

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: the `x` in `chmod u+x program_name` means "Execute Permissions" maybe you wanted to add `w` or "Write Permissions". Also, if you created the files under a different account, I would look at the file owner and try the `chown` command to change it.